# Where are required modules visible?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a problem understanding NodeJS require().
Basically I have this 3 files:

moongooseconfig.js

```
var config = require('./config');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = function() {
    var db = mongoose.connect(config.db);
     require('../app/models/user.server.model');

    return db;
}
```

usercontroller.js

```
var User = require('mongoose').model('User');

    exports.create = function(req, res, next) {
        var user = new User(req.body);
        user.save(function(err) {
            if(err) {
                return next(err);
            } else {
                res.json(user);
            }
        });
    };
```

And the server.js

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var mongoose = require('./config/mongooseconfig');
var express = require('./config/express');


var db = mongoose();
var app = express();
app.listen(3000);
```

My understanding of require was that the required module is only visible in the JS file which required the module.
I do not get why the user controller can use the mongoose Model 'User' without requiring the model file.
Yet the mongooseconfig requires the model file inside a function without saving it to a variable.

Can somebody tell me what happens there? Can every file access modules once they where required anywhere?
(Maybe I 'm just to blind, but I can not find the answer in the Node docs and googling "nodejs require scope" does not gave me any good results)

Comment: mongoose keeps a reference to each of its models. `require` is just regular JavaScript; it returns an object, and that object has no unusual restrictions on it.

Comment: So whenever I create a Model, mongoose will know? What is the point of requiering it then?

Comment: Without `require('../app/models/user.server.model');`, `app/models/user.server.model[.js]` will never run and register a model with mongoose.

Comment: Oh this is so obvious, isn't it? Thanks, did not thought about this. Was really confused about how this require works, yet it only creates the Model. I'd like to accept this as an anwser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments to answer:

mongoose keeps a reference to each of its models. `require` is just regular JavaScript; it returns an object, and that object has no unusual restrictions on it. The `require` in `mongooseconfig.js` is still necessary, though; without it, `app/models/user.server.model[.js]` will never run and register a model with mongoose.